# Highcharts - Force Categories in x-axis to be shown, even without data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm wondering if there's a way to force Highcharts to show ALL of the categories passed into its x-axis without giving filler data to hack it into working. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/cbargren/Sdnqu/ has 3 extra x-axis categories specified (foo, bar, baz) without any actual data (the series won't necessarily have data for the respective categories), and they aren't showing up on the chart. Can this be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the max on the xAxis to the index of the last category you want to show. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sdnqu/2/)

```
xAxis: {
       categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Pears', 'Oranges', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
       max:6
},
```

Comment: Any thoughts on making this work with literally no Series / Y Data at all?

Comment: The "min" property must also be set to 0, otherwise the categories won't be shown until one is found that actually contains any data. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27823608/highcharts-doesnt-display-all-categories