# Highcharts doesn't display all categories

Tags: highcharts

I'm using HighCharts but I don't understand why it doesn't display a categorie in xAxis if there is no data in yAxis...

I checked in API documentation and showEmpty equals true (default value)...

How can I display all categories despite I have more categories than data?

My js:

```
        userChart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart : {
            renderTo: 'highcharts',
            type: 'line',
            width: 950
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00',
                        '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30',
                        '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00',
                        '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30',
                        '18:00'],

        },
        yAxis: {

            min: 0,
            allowDecimals: false,
        },
        series: [{
            name: '1',
            data: data1,
        }],
    });
```

data1 contains only 16 entrances so Highcharts displays 16 categories...

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by telling the [`xAxis`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis) how many points to show regardless of how much data you have. This is a bit of a hack as the `xAxis` has no values exactly - but, it does have index values for each category starting with 0. So, you have 21 categories which means max index is 20. Then you `xAxis` property would look like:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['08:00', '08:30', '09:00', '09:30', '10:00',
                '10:30', '11:00', '11:30', '12:00', '12:30',
                '13:00', '13:30', '14:00', '14:30', '15:00',
                '15:30', '16:00', '16:30', '17:00', '17:30',
                '18:00'],
    min: 0,
    max: 20
},
```

Comment: I would also recommend skipping categories and using a datetime axis, since you are displaying datetime date.

Comment: Thank you wergeld, it works fine, i thought max works differently. In deed, I could do it, thx you for advice. :)