# Highcharts doesn't show all contents of x-axis

Tags: php, laravel, highcharts

The problem is when the x-axis categories array reaches index "50", it will not show all categories in x-axis. Instead it will just alternate. But when I print the `$chartArray['xAxis']['categories']` variable it has values from index 0 to index 50.

This is the figure up to index 49.

[image: complete index]

This is the figure up to index 50.

[image]

Comment: Actually its not an issue. you have to set max in that case:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27827407/4248328

Comment: It will show up to 52 but it still alternates (only prints the odd numbers)

Comment: Just to add: all of the points shows up (when you go in the graph part of the chart). It's just that in the categories part doesn't show everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set width of container to greater value.

Comment: Setting $chartArray['xAxis']['tickInterval'] = 1, doesn't work.

Comment: Just to add: all of the points shows up (when you go in the graph part of the chart). It's just that in the categories part doesn't show everything

Comment: I got what you mean, and I tried your fiddle by adding 52 categories and it doesn't show everything. It alternates (as what is shown in the screenshot). What I want to happen is to show 1 to 52 categories.

Comment: Now do one think, just increase width of your chart.

Comment: when you changes width of chart result box `category` changes : http://jsfiddle.net/kge7z7uy/2/

Comment: how to change the width?

Comment: didn't see any changes on the previous fiddles. Can you edit your answer and add it please? Thanks!

Comment: Now you understand, when chart shrink it automatically adjust its x-columns label(category) according to its width

Comment: kindly edit your answer so that I can accept it. Thanks!